# How to differentiate symbolically $\psi(x)=u_x$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, frechet-derivative

> Let $X\subset E$ where $E$ is a Banach space, and $[\alpha,\beta]\subset\Bbb R$. Then for $x\in X$ we define $u_x$ as the constant map defined by $[\alpha,\beta]\to E,\,t\mapsto x$. Then for the function $\psi$ defined by $x\mapsto u_x$ we clearly have $\psi\in C^\infty(X,C([\alpha,\beta],X))$ where $\partial\psi(x)h=u_h$.

I dont understand how is differentiated $\psi$ to obtain $\partial\psi$, that is, $\psi(x)=u_x$ but, how to differentiate it? Can someone show me, step by step, how we can obtain (formally) this result? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [definition of Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition), we shall find a bounded linear operator $A : X \to C([\alpha,\beta],X)$ such that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \| \psi(x + h) - \psi(x) - Ah \|_{C([\alpha,\beta],X)} }{ \|h\|_{X} } = 0.$$

Now, by the definition of $\psi$ this can be rewritten as
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \| u_{x + h} - u_{x} - Ah \|_{C([\alpha,\beta],X)} }{ \|h\|_{X} } = 0.$$

Here, for $t \in [\alpha,\beta]$ we have
$$(u_{x + h} - u_{x} - Ah)(t) = (x+h) - x - Ah = (1-A)h$$
so, since $\|\cdot\|_{C([\alpha,\beta],X)} = \|\cdot\|_u,$ the uniform norm defined by $\|f\|_u = \sup_x \|f(x)\|_X,$ we have
$$\|u_{x + h} - u_{x} - Ah\| = \sup_{t \in [\alpha,\beta]} \|(1-A)h\|_X = \|(1-A)h\|_X.$$

Thus we shall have
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \|(1-A)h\|_X }{ \|h\|_{X} } = 0.$$

This implies that
$\|1-A\|_{L(X, C([\alpha,\beta], X))} = \sup_{h \in X} \frac{\|(1-A)h\|_X}{\|h\|_X}$
must be zero, i.e. $A = 1.$

We set $\partial\psi(x) = A.$ This gives $\left(\partial\psi(x)h\right)(t) = Ah = h = u_h(t),$ i.e. $\partial\psi(x)h = u_h.$